# Compiler errors on Mac OS X when compiling Clementine

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, homebrew, macports

I tried to build [Clementine](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/) on Mac OS X Mountain Lion,

which ended up with many errors in its gstreamer dependencies to be specific.
The Clementine errors look like

```
 /usr/lib/clang/4.2/include/stddef.h:31: syntax error, unexpected '(' in 'typedef __typeof__(((int*)0)-((int*)0)) ptrdiff_t;' at '('
 /usr/lib/clang/4.2/include/stddef.h:35: syntax error, unexpected SIZEOF in 'typedef __typeof__(sizeof(int)) size_t;' at 'sizeof'
/usr/include/time.h:131: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'size_t strftime(char * restrict, size_t, const char * restrict, const struct tm * restrict) __asm("_" "strftime" );' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/time.h:131: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting identifier or '(' in 'size_t strftime(char * restrict, size_t, const char * restrict, const struct tm * restrict) __asm("_" "strftime" );' at ','
/usr/include/time.h:131: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting identifier or '(' in 'size_t strftime(char * restrict, size_t, const char * restrict, const struct tm * restrict) __asm("_" "strftime" );' at ','
/usr/include/time.h:131: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting identifier or '(' in 'size_t strftime(char * restrict, size_t, const char * restrict, const struct tm * restrict) __asm("_" "strftime" );' at ')'
/usr/include/pthread.h:256: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '                                      size_t * restrict);' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:265: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '                                      void ** restrict, size_t * restrict);' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:269: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '                                      size_t * restrict);' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:273: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'int pthread_attr_setguardsize(pthread_attr_t *, size_t );' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:282: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '                                      void *, size_t );' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:285: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'int pthread_attr_setstacksize(pthread_attr_t *, size_t );' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:377: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'int pthread_getname_np(pthread_t,char*,size_t) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/pthread.h:384: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'size_t pthread_get_stacksize_np(pthread_t);' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/stdio.h:255: syntax error, unexpected identifier in 'size_t fread(void * restrict, size_t, size_t, FILE * restrict);' at 'size_t'
/usr/include/stdio.h:255: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting identifier or '(' in 'size_t fread(void * restrict, size_t, size_t, FILE * restrict);' at ','
```

On my system I installed Xcode4.6 with command-line tools, also MacPorts and HomeBrew. Could it be the problem that there are conflicts among the three system? I tried to add more -I to the project makefiles but they didn't seem to fix the errors.